why livewire not working in mobile chrome
hello guys i make a new project with livewire V2 but It does not work only  in mobile chrome
my composer.json
   "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^3.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
        "josiasmontag/laravel-recaptchav3": "^1.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.40",
        "laravel/socialite": "^5.10",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.12"
    },`

my blade code
<button class="btn btn-question" id="question_btn_1" type="button"
                                wire:click="CheckAnswer('{{ $option1 }}',1)">
     {{ $option1 }}
</button>

and my php code is:
public function CheckAnswer($answer, $num_btn)
{
    if ($answer === $this->correct_answer) {
        click_question::record_answer_count($this->category_id, $this->question_id, 'true');
        statistics::record_score();
        if (Cookie::has('user_score')) {
            $new_score = Cookie::get('user_score') + 1;
            Cookie::queue(Cookie::forever('user_score', $new_score));
        }
        if (Auth::check()) {
            User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->increment('score_bread');
        }
        return $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('Reload', ['res_answer' => true, 'num_btn' => $num_btn]);
    }
    click_question::record_answer_count($this->category_id, $this->question_id, 'false');
    return $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('Reload', ['res_answer' => false, 'num_btn' => $num_btn, 'btn_correct' => $this->btn_correct]);
}

